# opening fm radio from the android application

Tags: android, audio

I am developing an application in which i need to open FM radio installed in the device.
that is only "FM radio" not "internet FM radio".

i know how to open another application using intent

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
 PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
 i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.sec.android.app.fm");
 i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
 startActivity(i);
```

But i need the package name of the fm radio application in every device,
Is there any way i can query for package name and open the fm radio application.

For now i am using samsung galaxy S..the fm radio package name in this device is

```
com.sec.android.app.fm
```

Is this package name will be same for every android devices.

Any one please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CyanogenMod uses `com.android.fm` for example. I'm not sure about other vendor-specific radio apps, but I'd say their package names are very likely to differ.

Right now two, not necessarily mutually exclusive options come to mind:

1. Using a heuristic approach to gather likely candidates for the radio app's package name*
2. Requiring the user to choose the radio app from a list of all installed packages

If your app has internet permissions, you could also collect the package names discovered using either method to compile a static list of package names to be included in your next release, in the hope of relieving new users from having to manually select their radio app.

*) 
Using `PackageManager.getInstalledApplications(...)` and scanning the returned `List` for occurrences of `".fm."`, `".fm"`, etc., you might be able to get a list of possible candidates.

Comment: Thanks Buddy..i think this will do..But if there is any package like "com.fmanager.xyz" this will open that package..right..

Comment: Well yes, that could be a problem. An option would be to apply scores to possible candidates, based on their likeliness to be an fm app, i.e. *.fm.* will get a higher score than .fm*, or packages ending with .fm getting the highest score. Also keep in mind, that they might not contain "fm" at all, but maybe "radio" or something similar!

This heuristic approach might seem rather fancy, the safer alternative would of course be option #2, asking the user to select a radio app on first launch....